# Tail-recursive solution to the coin change problem

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, f#

I am trying to solve the [coin change problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) with tail recursion. The recursive solutions I come across are usually something like this

```
let rec combinations (amount:int) (coins:list<int>) = 
    if amount = 0 then
        1
    elif coins.IsEmpty || amount < 0 then
        0
    else
        combinations (amount -  coins.Head) coins  +  combinations amount coins.Tail
```

clearly inefficient and non tail recursive. I tried to make the solution tail recursive myself:

```
let combinationsTail (amount:int) (coins:list<int>)  : int = 
    let rec go (amount:int) (sum:int) (coins:list<int>) =
        match amount,sum ,coins with 
        | _,_, [] -> 0
        | n,s,_ when n = 0 -> s
        | n,_,cs when n < 0 || cs.IsEmpty -> 0
        | n,s,h::t -> go (n - h) (n + s) t

    go amount 0 coins
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to implement a tail recursive solution to this problem? is it even possible?

Comment: *"it doesn't work."* In what way does it not work? It looks to me as though it type-checks, so perhaps you're seeing result that you didn't expect to see. If so, please update the question with test cases (inputs and their corresponding expected outputs).

Answer (score 3):

For achieving tail-recursiveness, you probably want to look into [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). [Here](http://www.fssnip.net/eU)'s an example applied to the Fibonacci sequence, which you could translate verbatim to the coins change problem, since both problems are dealing with aggregation of a recursive tree structure.

It's not the last word on efficiency.

```
let cc amount coins =
    let rec aux k = function
    | amount, _ when amount = 0 -> k 1
    | amount, _ when amount < 0 -> k 0
    | _, [] -> k 0
    | amount, hd::tl -> 
        let k' x =
            let k'' y = k (x + y)
            aux k'' (amount - hd, hd::tl)
        aux k' (amount, tl)
    aux id (amount, coins)
```